# Running Rally Release Dashboard Report from within SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, dojo, rally

New to Rally: I am trying to run rally release dashboard report in SharePoint. 
Although I have been successful with some basic reports that I can run from within SharePoint site by connecting to rally with the read key, I cannot do so for more complex reports that I want to run. It is simply not working from within SharePoint as Dojo is not found when it looks for it. I replaced the relative URLs with absolute and now server response from rally says that it looks for (/slm.....i.e. relative URL) and not the absolute URL. I don't know much about how Dojo library works but is there an easier way I can make the rally release dashboard show up when I add the code in SharePoint web part.
By the way the code that I am using for release dashboard is from rally github. (I am using SDK 1.32)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old mashup that uses unsupported BatchTookit which predates AppSDK 1 and LoginKey.
To troubleshoot, temporarily remove SharePoint as a factor. LoginKey is not specific to Sharepoint. It allows to load a Rally standard report or a Rally custom app outside of Rally without being prompted for credentials. Generally the first thing to check if the mashup loads in a browser, outside of Rally to make sure that the part of functionality described [here](https://help.rallydev.com/apps-outside-rally) is working. However, since this is an old mashup with dependencies that unfortunately not been maintained, there are 404 errors, for example for this file:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/js-lib/dojo/1.3.1/dijit/_CssStateMixin.js
```

which is indeed not at that location. Pasting that url in the browser returns 404.

Overcoming some other errors, even if running Chrome with  --allow-file-access-from-files option,and including the links below based on other errors in the javascript console of the browser is not enough:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/dojo/1.6/dijit/TitlePane.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/js-lib/dojo/1.3.1/dojo/fx/Toggler.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/js-lib/dojo/1.3.1/dojo/io/script.xd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already tried it with the basic charts to load it on the browser external from sharepoint and it works in both places but the more complex charts that use dojo library does not seem to render the charts in sharepoint. The Release dashboard rally source code from github when run on the browser ends up with just an empty timebox name dropdown.

Comment: it is not necessarily about being more complex. AppSDK 1 uses dojo, and straightforward App SDK 1 custom apps work externally, but this is an old mashup that may not be suitable for this purpose. You may submit a case with Rally support.